# Bash: avoiding filename expansion inside double bracket regular expression test

Tags: bash

I am trying to do a regular expression match with a variable that contains an asterisk.

The following set of commands in Bash does filename expansion with the asterisk in the variable on the left-hand side of the operator.

```
test='part1 * part2'
[[ "$test" =~ ^(.+)\ .\ (.+)$ ]] && echo $BASH_REMATCH
```

Results in: `part1 FILE1 FILE2 part2`

But it should result in: `part1 * part2`

I have searched and searched but cannot figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I realized while asking, the regular expression matching is working fine. There is *no* expansion happening inside the double brackets. The expansion is occurring *after* the match, when the result is echoed. The `$BASH_REMATCH` variable contains an asterisk, and needs to be double-quoted.

The correct set of commands is:

```
test='part1 * part2'
regex='^(.+) . (.+)$'
[[ "$test" =~ $regex ]] && echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
```

UPDATE: Set regular expression outside of test.

Comment: Quite right. (As a rule, you should *always* quote expansions unless given an explicit reason to do otherwise).

Comment: It's also good practice to declare the regex outside of the test because it's a) easier to read (no escaping necessary) and b) works for all Bash versions (see [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns) under "Regular Expressions").

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW., I updated the answer.